# I can't understand one step of this matrix norm proof

Tags: matrices, inequality, normed-spaces

I'm reading a multivariable calculus textbook for college, and before a Taylor series proof is given, a lemma is provided with its demonstration.

The lemma says:
Given a matrix $M(X)=
 \begin{pmatrix}
  & A_1\cdot X & \\
  & A_2\cdot X \\
  & \vdots  & \\
  & A_n\cdot X &
 \end{pmatrix}$
such that $A_i\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ and $X\in\mathbb{R}^n$. Then:
$$\|M(X)\|_\infty\le \left(\sum_{i=1}^{n} {\|A_i\|_\infty}^2\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}\|X\|$$

The proof is short. The author simply claims that given $Y\in\mathbb{R}^n, \|Y\|\le1$, then, because
$$\|M(X)\cdot Y\|^2=\sum_{i=1}^{n} |(A_i\cdot X)\cdot Y|^2$$
and for each $i$ between $1$ and $n$:
$$|(A_i\cdot X)\cdot Y|\le\|A_i\cdot X\|\|Y\|\le\|A_i\cdot X\|\le\|A_i\|_\infty\|X\|$$
Then the proof is done (literally, he doesn't end it). As far as my knowledge goes, that merely implies that $$\|M(X)\cdot Y\|\le\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n} {\|A_i\|_\infty}^2\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}\|X\|$$
But $\|M(X)\cdot Y\|\le\|M(X)\|_\infty$, because $\|Y\|\le1$. That is actually the way that $\|M(X)\|_\infty$ is defined in my textbook.
Please tell me if I'm missing something. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have $$\|M(X)\cdot Y\|\le\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n} {\|A_i\|_\infty}^2\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}\|X\|$$

Now observe that this inequality holds for all $Y$ with $\|Y\| \leq 1 $ and that the right side of the inequality is independent of $Y$, which makes it an upper bound for $\|M(X)\cdot Y\|$, therefore it must be greater or equal to the supremum of this expression.

Comment: Absolutely correct, except you should have written "greater or equal". I really don't know how I missed it, thank you very much!

Comment: @sbs95 You're of course right. We all miss obvious/easy things sometimes.